# Problem with contour line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, contour

I have a problem when I create a contour line from DEM, it's become sharp and not correct ( image attached ) .

DEM cell size = 5m
Contour interval = 5m
[image]

Comment: What is the projection of the DEM?

Comment: @ahmadhanb 
WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_40N

Comment: Can you attached a link to the DEM file?